# Restar y sumar campos de una tabla html

Tags: javascript, html

estoy intentando lograr que dentro de mi codigo al momento de ingresar los datos me reste y me sume los datos respectivamente. Ya logre hacer que me sumaran pero necesito que un campo me reste del total y no me sume. ¿Como podria hacerlo? Este es el codigo con el que logre realizar la suma.

```
function sumar() {
            var total = 0;
            $(".monto").each(function() {
                if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
                    total += 0;
                } else {
                    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
                }
            });
            //alert(total);
            document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total;

        }
```

Comment: Donde quieras restar, simplemente añade un "-" al valor mostrado... el parseFloat lo parseará a negativo y sumar un valor negativo equivale a restar

Comment: Tal vez sería buena una captura de la pagina así como el código html donde estas haciendo la suma.

Comment: Deberías quitar PHP de tus tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya viendo tu html, se ve que podemos mirar a los names de los input para saber cuando restar. Lo inuco que cambie es agarrar los names de las que quieres restar y comparar con los nombres cuando estamos en el loop.

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/sum-y-resta-vpocy)

```
        function calculaTotal() {
            var total = 0;
            $(".monto").each(function () {
                let num = parseFloat($(this).val());
                if (isNaN(num)) {
                    total += 0;
                } else if (["semipura_c_424", "semipura_c_776", "semipurad_d_282"].includes($(this).attr('name'))) {
                    // Restar
                    total -= num
                } else {
                    // Sumar
                    total += num
                }
            });

            document.getElementById("spTotal").innerHTML = total;
        }
```

Comment: Funciono perfecto. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Una solución sería tener un [atributo data](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos)

Un ejemplo si pruebas con las developer tools en esta misma página

```
div = $('[data-is-here-when]')[0]
div.dataset.isHereWhen // sm
```

Por lo que en tu caso podrías hacer `this.dataset.operation` y ver si ese campo quieres sumar o restar.